# Interactive Quiz: How to keep input values when hidden?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created an interactive quiz and created functions that showed the next question and goes back to the previous questions. My problem is that when it changes questions, the information I input in is erased. For example Question 1 and 2, I would write in an animal and then I go onto Question 3, but when I go back to Question 1 and 2, the animals I wrote in are gone. Same with the radio choices. Sorry if code is tedious, I'm just starting. Any tips on how I can fix that?

Quiz link: https://repl.it/GSiI/latest

```
    function initialize()
    {
      questionList = document.getElementsByClassName("questions");
      quizOutput = document.getElementById("showQuiz");
      beginBtn = document.getElementById("initiate");
      button = document.getElementById("button");
      next = document.getElementById("next");
      previous = document.getElementById("previous");
      questionIndex = 0;
      totalQuestions = questionList.length - 1;
    }

    function beginQuiz()
    {
     currentQuestion = questionList.item(questionIndex).innerHTML;
     button.style.visibility = "visible";
     quizOutput.innerHTML = currentQuestion;
     beginBtn.style.display = "none";
     quizOutput.style.display = "block";
    }

    function changeQuestion(factor)
    {
       if(factor == -1 && questionIndex > 0)
       {
        questionIndex--;
        currentQuestion = questionList.item(questionIndex).innerHTML;
        quizOutput.innerHTML = currentQuestion;
       }
       if(factor == 1 && questionIndex < totalQuestions)
       {
        questionIndex++;
        currentQuestion = questionList.item(questionIndex).innerHTML;
        quizOutput.innerHTML = currentQuestion;
       }
   }

    function writeNumber(el, num)
    {
     input = document.getElementById(el);
        if(input.value.length < 2)
        {
            input.value += num;
        }
    }

    function clearAnswer(el) 
    {
     document.getElementById(el).value = "";
    }

    function takeValues() 
    {
     var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
     var text = "";
     var i;
     for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) 
        {
          text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
        }
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }
```

Comment: Lots of ways you can skin this cat. The easiest is with global variables or a global object to store answers.

Comment: You should post your code here, or your question will likely get closed

Answer (score 0):

Its because every time you load a different question, you are actually removing the DOM elements without saving them.  When you return to the previous questions, you aren't loading their values from anywhere.  You need to build a state into your app for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using javascript FormData object to get entries of input values .
First removing all the "form" elements from your html but keep their inner elements.
Then make "showQuiz" div into a **form** element.
Then create 1 single **form** ( I set this form to have id "form1")  to contain all the questions and the submit button .
Then modify the javascript function changeQuestion as follow:

```
function changeQuestion(factor)
{
  var myform = document.getElementById("showQuiz");
  var fdata = new FormData(myform);
  var storeForm = document.getElementById("form1");
  var sdata = new FormData(storeForm);
  for (var pair of fdata.entries()) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByName(pair[0])[0];
    storeForm.elements[pair[0]].value = pair[1];
  }
  if(factor == -1 && questionIndex > 0)
  {
    questionIndex--;
    currentQuestion = questionList.item(questionIndex).innerHTML;
    quizOutput.innerHTML = currentQuestion;
  }
  if(factor == 1 && questionIndex < totalQuestions)
  {
    questionIndex++;
    currentQuestion = questionList.item(questionIndex).innerHTML;
    quizOutput.innerHTML = currentQuestion;
  }
  myform = document.getElementById("showQuiz");
  storeForm = document.getElementById("form1");
  fdata = new FormData(myform);
  sdata = new FormData(storeForm);
  for (var pair of sdata.entries()) {
      var fld = myform.elements[pair[0]];
      if (fld)
        fld.value = pair[1];
  }
}
```